# golearn - runtime error: cgo argument has Go pointer to Go pointer

Tags: pointers, go, machine-learning, liblinear

I'm new in go but I found [golearn](https://github.com/sjwhitworth) project which has lot of stars on github so I decided to give it a try with simple categorization problem. But with first attempt pointer problem appeared in `Train` method and I'm not sure if it's a bug in golearn bindings or is it related with wrong setup.

This is simplified version of code:

```
package main

import (
  _ "github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn/base"
  liblinear "github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn/linear_models"
)

func main() {
  labels, features := getFeatures()
  vocabulary := createVocabulary(features)
  words_matrix := countedMatrix(features, vocabulary)

  fmt.Println("labels:", labels)
  fmt.Println("words matrix:", words_matrix)

  solver_type := liblinear.L2R_LR_DUAL
  C := 10.0 
  eps := 0.01 
  bias := -1.0 

  parameter := liblinear.NewParameter(solver_type, C, eps)
  problem := liblinear.NewProblem(words_matrix, categories, bias)

  model := liblinear.Train(problem, parameter)

  prediction_vector := countedVector(tokenize("something to predict here"), vocabulary)
  fmt.Println("prediction vector:", prediction_vector)

  prediction := liblinear.Predict(model, prediction_vector)
  fmt.Println("prediction:", prediction)
}
```

And this is output i get:

```
labels: [6 8 9 10 11 12 14 15 16 17]
words matrix: [[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0] [0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1] [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0] [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1] [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1]]
panic: runtime error: cgo argument has Go pointer to Go pointer

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x83d620, 0xc8200d7510)
    /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/runtime/panic.go:481 +0x3e6
github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn/linear_models.Train(0xc820102420, 0xc820015e80, 0xa)
    /home/me/gocode/src/github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn/linear_models/liblinear.go:61 +0x11d
main.main()
    /home/me/gocode/src/mlservice/main.go:144 +0x62b
exit status 2
```

Should I report issue or fix code (please help me if fix is possible)

Comment: If new to Go: Take the tour of Go. Once taken play around with packages which do use neither cgo nor unsafe. Do such stuff once you really know Go.

Comment: It looks like `github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn/linear_models` isn't correctly using cgo. It's unsafely passing Go memory to a C library, and I wouldn't use it.

Comment: I used following workaround and code works fine `export GODEBUG=cgocheck=0`

Comment: Finally i replaced `golearn` with `github.com/lazywei/lineargo`. Thanks for feedback.